# Remove NULL from end of string

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

How do I get rid of NULL at the end of line here?

> WYOMING MI NEW JERSEY 07728 COMPUTER REPAIR TECHNULL

```
$phrases = array("NEW YORK NY", "NEW JERSEY", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH CAROLINA",     "COMPUTER REPAIR TECH","YORK NY","07728","WYOMING MI","WYOMING MINNESOTA");
$string = ("I live in wyoming Minnesota, but used to live in New Jersey 07728 working     as a computer repair tech.");
$string = strtoupper($string);

$matches = stringSearch($phrases, $string);

var_dump($matches);

function stringSearch($phrases, $string){
    $phrases1 = trim(implode('|', $phrases));
    $phrases1 = str_replace(' ', '\s', $phrases1);

    preg_match_all("/$phrases1/s", $string, $matches);

    $value = implode(' ', array_filter($matches[0]));
    echo $value;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the `var_dump` that was causing the issue!

Give this a try!

```
$phrases = array("NEW YORK NY", "NEW JERSEY", "SOUTH DAKOTA", "SOUTH CAROLINA",     "COMPUTER REPAIR TECH","YORK NY","07728","WYOMING MI","WYOMING MINNESOTA");
$string = ("I live in wyoming Minnesota, but used to live in New Jersey 07728 working     as a computer repair tech.");
$string = strtoupper($string);

$matches = stringSearch($phrases, $string);

//var_dump($matches);  // <---------- comment this out!!!

function stringSearch($phrases, $string){
    $phrases1 = trim(implode('|', $phrases));
    $phrases1 = str_replace(' ', '\s', $phrases1);

    preg_match_all("/$phrases1/s", $string, $matches);

    $value = implode(' ', array_filter($matches[0]));
    if($value){
        echo $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm glad it did, please don't forget to mark as the answer :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

The function does not return anything. The `$matches` variable will therefore contain the value `null`. That value is output by `var_dump($matches)`, right after the string is `echo`ed inside the function.

In other words, it's not part of the result string, those a separate outputs. Remove `var_dump($matches)` and it's gone.